# How to show a simple value from a meteor collection in a meteor template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to display an object from a collection in meteor using handlebars.

I have this example about what I have:

Collection: Transactions.

Server side:

```
Meteor.publish('getTransaction', function(transactionid){
    return Transactions.findOne({transactionid:transactionid});
});
```

Client side:

HTML

```
    <template name='MainTransac'>

    <body>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">General information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                       <tr>
                        <td>TransactionID:</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td>{{transactionid}}</td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>    
                  </table>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </body>
   </template>
```

JS

```
Template.MainTransac.onCreated(function(){   
this.subscribe('getTransaction',Router.current().params.transactionid); 
});
```

As you can see I have receiving the trasactionid from another page. But I am not able to know how can I show the table with the transaction id or any other field from the transaction document.

I really appreciate all your help about it.

If you have any question just let me know, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

As first you have to create a helper which will contains your collection data:

```
Template.MainTransac.helpers({
  transaction: function(){ return Transactions.find(); }
});
```

Then you will be able to include that helper in your template:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>TransactionID:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
{{#with transaction}}
  <td>{{transactionid}}</td>
{{/with}}
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I have added the helpers and try again according with your information and I am not able to get the value :/ the app does not show any error on client or  server side, just do not change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that `Transactions.findOne({transactionid:transactionid});` returns anything ? Try assign it to a variable and log that variable on the server side.

Comment: Yes it returns the Transaction Object correctly. I did that test and everything was working as expected.

Comment: I edited my answer a little bit. Please try again. You should probably want to test if the `transaction` *helper* function returns the correct data.

Comment: Not working :( I have tested it in different ways and not result

Answer (score 0):

A publication must return a *cursor* or an *array of cursors*. You have:

```
Meteor.publish('getTransaction', function(transactionid){
    return Transactions.findOne({transactionid:transactionid});
});
```

which is returning an object.

Just change the `.findOne()` to `.find()`

```
Meteor.publish('getTransaction', function(transactionid){
    return Transactions.find({transactionid:transactionid});
});
```

Then your `publish()` will work as will your `subscribe()`. You still need to select the right data context for your template via a template helper.

Comment: Hi Michel. Thank you for your information, I have change the .findOne() to .find(). However I am still not showing the information. Could you give an example regarding this part: "You still need to select the right data context for your template via a template helper". That's because maybe the helper and the handlebar are the ones with the error.